# Windows 8 Hangs at first login ( domain account )

Tags: domain, virtual-machines, login, windows-8, windows-8.1

Good morining,

i'm experiencing a systematic problem with new fresh joined to domain Virtual Machines with windows 8 and windows 8.1 installed operating system.

The issue is that at first login the machines  stay idle at welcome screen with the little dots dancing around again and again

The workaround, not applicable in an enterprise environment, consists in rebooting the VM and at next login everithing goes as it should from the beginning.

Someone is affected from the same problem and has found a kb or a solution for it?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, what do the event logs say? What troubleshooting have you done to narrow down the cause of the issue?  Have any `run once` entries or template customizations that might be causing this?  (And so on.)  There;s just not enough here to give an educated answer.

Comment: I'm looking event log and the only things that seems to be related is a event 1112 related to Group policy client side extention that must be loaded before complete the login of the user. About customization no run once was set, only join to domain is set and generate new sid.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! There appears to be little to no research done on this issue up front and/or there's very little for someone here to go on to assist you.  It is recommended that you post things you've already tried, options you are considering, or errors that you are experiencing.  The more details you provide (logs, screenshots, etc.), the better the experts here can assist you.

Comment: update: I haven't found the solution yet but it seems that this problem happens also in physical machines